# Combine two text files with different line numbers - BASH

Tags: bash

I have two files: a.txt b.txt
the a contain 3 lines:

```
id1
id2
id3
```

b.txt:

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
```

The desired combined output of c.txt:

```
id1 100
id2 200
id3 300
id1 400
id2 500
id3 600
id1 700
```

Any idea how can this be done in bash?
Thanks!

Comment: If `a.txt` is always small like this, store its content into an array. Then loop over b.txt, and apply cyclically the respective line from your a.txt array.

Answer (score 0):

You can `cat` the first file several times. To find out how many times, count the lines in both the files and divide the numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
lines_a=$(wc -l < a.txt)
lines_b=$(wc -l < b.txt)
(( repeat = 1 + lines_b / lines_a ))
exec 4< b.txt
for (( i=0 ; i<repeat ; ++i )) ; do
    cat a.txt
done | while read id ; do
    read -u4 value || break
    printf '%s %s\n' "$id" "$value"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A common trick is to read the shorter file into an array and then just loop. Awk makes this easy, though it could be done in Bash too.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { keep[++n] = $0; next }
{ i = FNR%n ? FNR%n : n; print keep[i], $0 }' a.txt b.txt
```

If `b.txt` is the shorter file, just flip the order of the arguments, and maybe the order in which you `print` things.